# Drop row in Pandas Series and clean up index

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Pandas Series and based on a random number I want to pick a row (5 in the code example below) and drop that row. When the row is dropped I want to create a new index for the remaining rows (0 to 8). The code below:

```
print 'Original series: ', sample_mean_series
print 'Length of original series', len(sample_mean_series)
sample_mean_series = sample_mean_series.drop([5],axis=0)
print 'Series with item 5 dropped: ', sample_mean_series
print 'Length of modified series:', len(sample_mean_series)
print sample_mean_series.reindex(range(len(sample_mean_series)))
```

And this is the output:

```
Original series:  
0    0.000074
1   -0.000067
2    0.000076
3   -0.000017
4   -0.000038
5   -0.000051
6    0.000125
7   -0.000108
8   -0.000009
9   -0.000052
Length of original series 10
Series with item 5 dropped:  
0    0.000074
1   -0.000067
2    0.000076
3   -0.000017
4   -0.000038
6    0.000125
7   -0.000108
8   -0.000009
9   -0.000052
Length of modified series: 9
0    0.000074
1   -0.000067
2    0.000076
3   -0.000017
4   -0.000038
5         NaN
6    0.000125
7   -0.000108
8   -0.000009
```

My problem is that the row number 8 is dropped. I want to drop row "5    NaN" and keep -0.000052 with an index 0 to 8. This is what I want it to look like:

```
0    0.000074
1   -0.000067
2    0.000076
3   -0.000017
4   -0.000038
5    0.000125
6   -0.000108
7   -0.000009
8   -0.000052
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Somewhat confusingly, `reindex` does not mean "create a new index".  To create a new index, just assign to the `index` attribute.  So at your last step just do `sample_mean_series.index = range(len(sample_mean_series))`.

Comment: Thanks for that clear & concise answer!  However, I'm confused what IS happening in Ahlden's example.  Is the re-index saying, "create a new series with no gaps in the indices, where any missing indices are filled with NaN values"?  It seems that's what's happening, but that seems crazy.  Also, would this work if the indices are a, b, c, e instead of 0, 1, 2, 4 ?

Comment: @MikeWilliamson: Yes, that's basically it.  Using `reindex[blah]` just selects rows, basically like doing `df.ix[blah]`, and like that it gives you NaN if the ones you ask for don't exist.  It does have some options for filling in the NaNs, but I've never really understood the point of reindex, let alone its name.

Comment: actually, there's a reset_index method that automatically numbers the rows for you.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a one-liner:

```
In [1]: s
Out[1]:
0   -0.942184
1    0.397485
2   -0.656745
3    1.415797
4    1.123858
5   -1.890870
6    0.401715
7   -0.193306
8   -1.018140
9    0.262998
```

I use the `Series.drop` method to drop row 5 and then use `reset_index` to re-number the indices to be consecutive. Without using `reset_index`, the indices would jump from 4 to 6 with no 5.

By default, `reset_index` will move the original index into a `DataFrame` and return it alongside the series values. Passing `drop=True` prevents this from happening.

```
In [2]: s2 = s.drop([5]).reset_index(drop=True)

In [3]: s2
Out[3]:
0   -0.942184
1    0.397485
2   -0.656745
3    1.415797
4    1.123858
5    0.401715
6   -0.193306
7   -1.018140
8    0.262998
Name: 0
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: I explained my answer and updated it to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

To drop rows in a **dataframe** and clean up index:

```
b = df['amount'] > 10000
df_dropped = df.drop(df[~b].index).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace = True)
```

Will do exactly what you want.

When you reset the index, the old index is added as a column, and a new sequential index is used. You can use the drop parameter to avoid the old index being added as a column.

Comment: Keep in mind that the question is from 2013.. a zilion years ago in programming so if you want to make your answer make sense add some version numbers and refer to "overtime" changes in libraries, etc. End of Review.